# Loading url in ionic shows blank screen

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have searched on web but got nothing concrete about this issue.
I'm using ionic v1, in which I'm loading my adfs url to ask user for login though adfs web page but only on some phones I see login page and on others I see blank screen. 
I tried debugging it but I got nothing[only the url] constructive so far. 
I'm loading url using

```
window.open("https://inve....", '_system');
```

So far we've encountered with this issue on Android phones only, but I'm targeting iPhones also.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you tried crosswalk?

Comment: I'm just 2-3 days away from production can't try anything new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

app browser and loading adfs login page with url in it for this ionic app.

The prob I was facing was because of certificates, The server is using self signed certificate so when I'm trying to load it on the device who don't even opened server pages on browsers the app used to stuck on white screen.

If your server is signed with proper certified certificate by CA then this prob will not occur as browsers able to validate these certificates easily. 
That's why earlier with right certificate My android app used to work on all android phones.

Here is [link](https://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/android-webview-with-https-loadurl-shows-blankempty-page/) to understand the process if you want to specify the certificates locally.

For other guys looking for help in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

For open external url you need to use plugin for ionic which is compatible for both android and ios:

Install cordova-plugin-inappbrowser using below line:

**cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser**

after that put this code in your html file:

```
<button class="button" ng-click="openurl('https://..........')">
      Click here
</button>
```

and then call click event through controller:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaInAppBrowser) {

   var options = {
      location: 'yes',
      clearcache: 'yes',
      toolbar: 'no'
   };

   $scope.openurl = function (url) {
          window.open(url, '_system', options);  
    }

 OR

   $scope.openurl = function (url) {
        $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(url, '_system', options);  
   }


})
```

Also change in your config.xml file

```
 <allow-intent href="*" />
 <allow-navigation href="*" />
 <allow-intent href="http://*/*" launch-external="yes" />
 <allow-intent href="https://*/*" launch-external="yes" />
 <feature name="StatusBar">
     <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
 </feature>
```

For further reference you can go through:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Comment: you are using `window.open` or `openurl` ? Plz mention android version on which you are able to see web page and vice versa

Comment: @MobileEvangelist this plugin working fine for me for android as well as ios.

Comment: @sam : `openurl` is my click event name..you can use any name for this and `window.open` is a browser event..you can also user `$cordovaInAppBrowser.open instaed` of `window.open`..initially both are same..! And this is working perfect in android 4.1 versions

Comment: @MobileEvangelist : I have forgot to mention that this plugin requires changes in config.xml file also put this in your file that might solve your problem.`<feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
    </feature>                                                                                    
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" launch-external="yes" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" launch-external="yes" />`

Comment: @Hitarthipanchal My bad `openurl` was a typo. Anyway I think InAppBrowser plugin works with `cordova whitelist` plugin. So he does'nt need to specify all these parameters in his config.xml.

Comment: @sam : I knw but I found somewhere that we have to add references if plugin not working for you..and that is the reason that I have mentioned that things.

Comment: Guys I've tried these different approaches for this but trust me it's something else. I'm investigating ASA I'll get to know will update here.. thanks for your help